# Can session scope beans be used with Spring Session and GemFire?

Tags: spring-session, spring-data-gemfire

Can "session" scope beans be used with *Spring Session* and Pivotal GemFire?

When using *Spring Session* for "session" scope beans, *Spring* creates an extra `HttpSession` for this bean.  Is this an existing issue?

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Any solution for above query?

Comment: Any questions about the solution and answer below?

Comment: 1 last comment... I have built an example in the latest release of _Spring Session Data GemFire_, *2.0.0.RC1* (just released yesterday... https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/07/spring-session-data-geode-gemfire-2-0-0-rc1-available) that demonstrates how Spring "_session_" scoped proxies work in the context of a _Spring Boot_ application configured with _Spring Session_ (using GemFire/Geode as the provider).  See here...https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-session-data-geode-build/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html5/guides/boot-gemfire-with-scoped-proxies.html

Answer (score 10):

Regarding...

> *Can session scoped beans be used with Spring Session and GemFire?*

Yes!

In fact, it does not matter which underlying "provider" is used with *Spring Session* either.  For example, either [*Spring Session* with GemFire/Geode](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/tree/2.0.0.M1) ([docs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-session-data-geode-build/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/)) or [Spring Session with Redis](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/2.0.0.M3/spring-session-data-redis) ([docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html5/#httpsession-redis)), etc, can be used and it will work just the same (in the same way).

As for...

> *If using Spring Session for session scoped beans Spring creates extra HttpSession for this bean, is this an existing issue?*

Well, this is **not** exactly true.

You have to understand the underlying technologies in play here and how they all work together, including *Spring Session*, the *Spring Framework*, the *Servlet Framework*, your *Web container* (e.g. Tomcat), which is bound by the contract specified in the Java EE *Servlet* spec, and any other technologies you may have applied (e.g. *Spring Security's* Web support).

If we dive deep into *Spring's* architecture/infrastructure, you will begin to understand how it works, why it works and why your particular statement ("*Spring creates an **extra** HttpSession for this bean*") is **not** correct.

First, *Spring Session* registers an all important *Servlet* [`Filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html), the [`o.s.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.0.0.M3/api/org/springframework/session/web/http/SessionRepositoryFilter.html).

There are many different ways to do this, and the *Javadoc* for `javax.servlet.Filter` essentially hints that this is done via the Web Application "*deployment descriptor*".

Of course, given our menagerie of configuration options today, a Web Application *deployment descriptor* is pretty loosely defined, but we commonly know this to mean `web.xml`.  However, that is not the only way in which we can configure, essentially, the Web Application's `ServletContext`.

*Spring* supports both `web.xml` based *deployment descriptors* as well as *JavaConfig* using the *Servlet* (3.0+) API.

In `web.xml` you would [register](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html5/#xml-servlet-container-initialization) (for [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.0.M3/samples/xml/redis/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L19-L28)) the *Spring Frameworks'* [`o.s.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html), that delegates to an actual `javax.servlet.Filter` implementation (when *Spring Session* is in play, that would be the `o.s.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter`, of course) which is also declared/defined as a "*bean*" (first [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.0.M3/samples/xml/redis/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/session.xml#L13), then [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.0.M3/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/config/annotation/web/http/SpringHttpSessionConfiguration.java#L124-L138)) in the *Spring* container.  This is necessary in order to auto-wire (inject) the appropriate *Spring Session* [`o.s.session.SessionRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.0.0.M3/api/org/springframework/session/SessionRepository.html) implementation (also a *Spring* managed bean defined in the container, e.g. for [Redis](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.0.M3/spring-session-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java#L120-L140)) that knows how to delegate (HTTP) `Session` state management to the underlying "provider".

In the *JavaConfig* approach, the registration is performed via the core *Spring Framework's* [`o.s.web.WebApplicationInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) concept.  Read the Javadoc for more details.

Well, *Spring Session* provides such a `WebApplicationInitializer` to initialize (HTTP) Session management, the [`o.s.session.web.context.AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.0.0.M3/api/org/springframework/session/web/context/AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer.html).  Typically, when using *Spring's* [Java-based Container Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java) and/or [Annotation configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-annotation-config) approach, a developer would create a class that extends this *Spring Session* provided class and [register](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html5/#java-servlet-container-initialization) the necessary configuration (e.g. connection criteria) for the underlying Session management provider; for [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.0.M3/samples/javaconfig/redis/src/main/java/sample/Initializer.java#L22-L27) (see also [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.0.M3/samples/javaconfig/redis/src/main/java/sample/Config.java#L24-L31)).  The `Config` class is [annotated](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.0.M3/samples/javaconfig/redis/src/main/java/sample/Config.java#L24) with `@EnableRedisHttpSession` which [imports](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.0.M3/spring-session-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/EnableRedisHttpSession.java#L57) the *Spring* `@Configuration` class that declares/defines the appropriate *Spring Session* `SessionRepository` implementation for the "provider" (e.g. again [Redis](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.0.M3/spring-session-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java#L120-L140)), which is needed by the *Servlet* `Filter` (again `SessionRepositoryFilter`).

If you look at what the *Spring Session* `AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer` does, you will see that it [registers](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.0.M3/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/context/AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer.java#L117) the *Spring Session*, `SessionRepositoryFilter`, indirectly via *Spring Framework's* `DelegatingFilterProxy`... from insert, then [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.0.M3/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/context/AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer.java#L126-L128), then [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.0.M3/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/context/AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer.java#L133) and finally, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.0.M3/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/context/AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer.java#L195-L206).

As you can see, the *Spring Session* `SessionRepositoryFilter` is [positioned **first**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.0.M3/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/context/AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer.java#L205) in the chain of *Servlet* `Filters`.  The `!insertBeforeOtherFilters` is negated since the parameter in [`javax.servlet.FilterRegistration.Dynamic.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, isMatchAfter, urlPatterns...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/) is "**isMatchAfter**".

This is essential, since the *Spring Session's* `o.s.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter` [replaces](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/2.0.0.M3/spring-session-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/web/http/SessionRepositoryFilter.java#L153-L164) both of the `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` and `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse`.  Specifically, by replacing the `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`, *Spring Session* can provide an implementation of `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` (when `HttpServletRequest.getSession(..)` is called) that is backed by *Spring Session* and the provider of the developer's choice (e.g. Redis, GemFire), the whole purpose of *Spring Session* in the first place.

So, the *Servlet* `Filters` see the HTTP request/response before any framework code (e.g. *Spring Framework's* session scoped bean infrastructure), and especially before any of the Web Application's `Controllers` or `Servlets`, get to see the HTTP request/response.

So, when the core *Spring Framework's* session scoped bean infrastructure sees the (HTTP) *Servlet* request/response, it sees what *Spring Session* handed it, which is just an implementation the regular `javax.servlet` interfaces (e.g. `HttpSession`) backed by *Spring Session*.

Looking at the core *Spring Framework's* [`o.s.web.context.request.SessionScope`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/SessionScope.html) "custom" implementation (which handles bean references/bean lifecycles for session scoped beans declared/defined in the *Spring* container), which extends `o.s.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope`, you see that it just delegates to the [`o.s.web.context.request.SessionRequestAttributes`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletRequestAttributes.html) class. This class is created primarily by *Spring's* `DispatcherServlet`, and defines all of its operations (e.g. [`setAttribute(name, value, scope)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletRequestAttributes.html#setAttribute-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-int-)) in terms of the "provided" scope defined by the bean (definition) in question.  See the [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletRequestAttributes.java#L161-L174) for more details.  So the bean gets added to the appropriate HTTP session.

Sure, *Spring* ["will" create a new](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletRequestAttributes.java#L170) `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` on the first HTTP request, but not without *Spring Session's* infrastructure knowing about it, since what *Spring* is using in this case is an implementation of `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` backed by *Spring Session's* "`Session`".

Also, [`getSession(true)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/context/request/ServletRequestAttributes.java#L109-L130) is also just an indication that the `HttpSession` is "**allowed**" to be created if it does not already exist!  A *Servlet* container simply does not keep creating new HTTP sessions for every HTTP request, so long as the session ID can be determined from the HTTP request (which is done via either URL injection... `jsessionid` or with a cookie, typically).  See the [`javax.servlet.HttpServletRequest.getSession(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession-boolean-) for more details.

Anyway, the only other caveat to this entire story is, you need to make sure, especially for GemFire, that...

1. The *Spring* "session" scoped beans defined in the container are serializable, either using Java Serialization, or 1 of [GemFire's serialization strategies](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/developing/data_serialization/chapter_overview.html).  This includes whatever the bean references (other beans, object types, etc) unless those "references" are declared `transient`.  NOTE: I am not entirely certain GemFire Reflection-based PDX serialization approach is entirely "aware" of "*transient*" fields.  Be conscious of this.
2. You must make certain that the classes serialized in the session are on the GemFire Servers classpath.

I am [working on a configuration option](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/issues/2) for Spring Session Data Geode/GemFire at the moment to support PDX, but that is **not** available yet.

Anyway, I hope this helps clear up the muddy waters a bit.  I know it is a lot to digest, but it all should work as the user expects.

I will also add that I have not tested this either.  However, after reviewing the code, I am pretty certain this should work.

I have [made it a task](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/issues/3) to add tests and samples to cover this situation in the near future.

Cheers!
-John